# Unable to use linux unallocated space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I had a windows-Linux dual boot on my PC and decided to get rid of windows because most of my work has been down on the Linux partition. I've deleted windows but for some reason can't add the unallocated space into my Linux root and home partitions (sda5 and sda8). I have GParted live, and it won't give me the option to add even 1MiB to my desire partitions. I try to scan the web for solutions but everyone facing this problem with "extended" partition, which I don't have.

[image: Gparted Image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not using LVM, so your partitions have to be continuous - you can't take two non-adjacent disk slices and make them one partition.

`sda5` is squashed between two swap partitions. There's no adjacent free space, so it can't be extended neither left nor right. `sda8` has ~1GB of free space to the right and could be extended, but you can't do that on a live system while the partition is in use (well, it's possible, but difficult and not necessary in your scenario).

So:

0. **Make backups.** Manipulating partitions can always result in data loss.
1. Boot Ubuntu from USB, so partitions aren't mounted and can be edited.
2. Move `sda6` swap to the far left, adjacent to `sda`.
3. Resize `sda5`. It will take a while, since extending a partition left is a two-step process: first the tool moves it left to the new starting location (copying its contents), then extends it right.